# How to show @annotions and Dependency Injection in UML Diagram

Tags: uml

Folks,
How you show DI and @annotations on UML Diagram?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The best choice imho for this purposes would be stereotypes with tagged values. UML can be extended with new elements - stereotypes, which might have key-value pairs (tagged values). This suffices to describe everything annotations can. In the other answer you can see a concrete example of stereotypes.
Even simpler approach would be to use notes to add more details.